# validations are running while running test classes

Tags: apex, deployment, validation

validations are running while running test classes .How to fix that.

While deployment validation are running and failing deployment due to same.
Please suggest how to fix as test classes are many and need fix to do deployment without changing test class

Answer (score 2):

You can't skip validations. That's the point of them. You should be using a [Test Data Factory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm) to produce records that will not violate the validation rules. Unfortunately, you're at a point where you'll have to spend some time cleaning this up, but it's necessary. Failure to do so will lead to these sorts of scenarios in the future, and it will get worse the longer you wait. You might be able to turn off the validations temporarily before a deployment, but this is not sustainable, and amounts mostly to just "kicking the can down the street." You can put it off temporarily, but keep in mind that anything failing in a unit test also means your code may fail in production. You do not want to be in that scenario.

Comment: thanks, ya for time being i want to run the deployment .do i need to Inactive validation rules from Metadata .

Comment: @sam There's a checkbox you can uncheck while editing the Validation rule. Again, do this at your own peril.